# how do i reduce a 17000 page document to less pages by reducing font?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I have a big pdf. I tried to convert word then changed the font size of the entire document but it leaves giant spaces in between the pages, I tried to make it continuous but I cannot figure it out. please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to reduce the number of pages you can group them like 2 pages in 1 or so. I mean:

```
---------------
|  ---   ---  |
|  |1|   |2|  |
|  ---   ---  |
---------------
```

That would make it 17k/2 = 8500 pages, but you could go with 4 per page and get 4250 pages.

Maybe this works for you? If not, can you clarify what you mean by

> leaves giant spaces in between the pages

Does it show like text reduced on top of each page with big blank on the bottom?
Or does it leave a bunch of blank pages?

Answer (score 0):

Converted documents are always a pain to edit in Word. How bad it is depends on the original content and conversion process, but it is never straightforward. Conversion gives you something that looks good but may have all sorts of formatting anomalies.

Try the following in a copy of your document.

- Replace ^m with ^p.
- Replace ^b with ^p.

This is drastic. It removes all manual page breaks and all section breaks. It may leave you with substantial work.

I would advise going through and using styles to format your document. Start by formatting everything in the normal style. Then go to your headings and apply the relevant heading styles.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem when doing a mail merge (not a pdf, I realize, but still had lots of blank space!) The data source I was merging into the document called for over a hundred pages of mail merge-ready template, and I only had 2 pages of template. Every time the template "started over" there would be about 3/4 of a page of blank space. Backspacing did not get rid of it. Showing the paragraph marks did not help. I found clicking right after the last word before the odd space started and then clicking "delete" on my keyboard fixed the problem. I hope this is helpful!